# In bootstrap, I can't change the colour of list elements with custom css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cant change the colour of navbar elements elements when working with bootstrap. Every other style like font size, font weight etc works but the colour doesn't change. I've tried to style the hyperlinks within the list elements too but it doesn't change anything. Every other style seems to be working fine. It worked when I changed it in the actual bootstrap.css file but that was a little inconvenient finding that particular line of code first and then changing it the style for it. It looks like my custom css fails to override the default bootstrap css when it comes to changing the colour property in navbar. Any idea why? Thanks

Here's the code:

```
.nav li {
    color: red;
        }
```

Comment: If none of the above answers work please paste you code in (HTML and CSS). :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just check in your Head tag; that you have mentioned your main css file after bootstrap link.
Might be this will be the one case.

Else post your code ; i will figure out the problem.

Comment: That should be comment rather then answer. If you can't then please don't spam on site by this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

tyr this way

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a{
  color:red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.navbar-nav>li>a{
    color:red;
}
or this
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a{
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code to:

```
.nav li {
color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: When using bootstrap (or in general) it is a bad idea to use `!important` since it can't be overwritten again.

Comment: Yes, @LuukSkeur is right. Please use this method only if you are not using too many css libraries/files in your webpage.